# PHP Zend OpenID provider and DotNetOpenAuth OpenID relying party error

Tags: openid, dotnetopenauth

I have implemented the OpenID Provider with the Zend provider and updated the storage with the 3rd party storage. It works fine.

I used a consumer from LightOpenID in PHP and that works fine.

Now I have tried to create another consumer(OpenIdRelyingPartyMvc) with the help of http://www.dotnetopenauth.net, but I get this error:

> The following required parameters were missing from the DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.Messages.PositiveAssertionResponse message: openid.claimed_id

Can I have some example for similar kind of implementaion or can I have some clue where I might went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `openid.claimed_id` parameter was required in OpenID 2.0, but not in OpenID 1.1.  So most likely your OpenID Provider (Zend) only implements OpenID 1.1.  From this we can derive several things:

1. Consider upgrading your OpenID Provider to OpenID 2.0.  It is more secure and capable.
2. The OpenIDs that your Zend Provider issues are probably claiming to be OpenID 2.0 compatible when they should only be claiming 1.1 compatibility.  DotNetOpenAuth works fine against 1.1 and 2.0, but not against a 1.1 that pretends to be 2.0 but isn't.

If you need help understanding how the Provider appears to be 2.0 but really is 1.1, please add either a link to your Provider or the content of one of your OpenID pages (the OpenID URL you issue to a user)  to your question.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, i tried with php-openId as provider and http://www.dotnetopenauth.net as consumer and it works fine.